# Подключение к Google Ads по API через токен

Tags: r, rstudio, google-adwords

Хотелось бы узнать - возможно ли сделать токен, с помощью которого можно было бы подключаться к Google Ads по API без входа в учетную запись Google, данные из которой необходимо получать по API.
На данный момент для подключения к API Google Ads использую RStudio (и язык R соответственно) через библиотеку rgoogleads. После первичного подключения к API Google Ads запрашивается вход в учетную запись и после этого необходимо предоставить разрешение приложению (прослойка, которой необходимо предоставить доступ к данным Google Ads через аккаунт Google) на управление Google Ads. После этого в папке AppData\Local\gargle\gargle\Cache создается кэшированный файл доступа (возможно некий вид токена). Этот файл работает как токен и позволяет работать с Google Ads по API без необходимости каждый раз входить в учетную запись Google и предоставлять разрешения для приложения-прослойки. Но есть одно но - иногда этот файл из "AppData\Local\gargle\gargle\Cache" пропадает (или просто ломается) и появляется необходимость снова входить в учетную запись и предоставлять разрешения для приложения-прослойки. Так как это уже произошло дважды за две недели, похоже у данного закэшированного "токена" есть некий срок годности, после которого он больше не подходит и требуется создание нового. В связи с этим появился вопрос - а возможно ли сделать токен, который бы не имел срока годности или этот срок был очень большим?

Как пример - вот как подключение выглядит сейчас

```
library(rgoogleads)

gads_auth_configure(path = '#######Название файла с токеном для настроек######.json')
gads_auth(
  email = '#####Почта аккаунта с которого получаем данные по API#####@gmail.com',
  developer_token = '######### Токен уровня Базовый доступ ###########'
)
```

P.S. Для примера, необходимый пример работы токена сейчас используется для подключения через сервисный аккаунт к таблице в Google Spreadsheets с помощью библиотеки googlesheets4.

```
library(googlesheets4)
gs4_auth(path = "hallowed-glider-328412-a4417dc713b0.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

я автор пакета `rgoogleads`, лучше вопросы по этому пакету задавать мне на GitHub по ссылке - https://github.com/selesnow/rgoogleads/issues

Теперь по вашему вопросу, для авторизации `rgoogleads` под капотом использует пакет `gargle`, собственно, как и пакет `googlesheets4`. Но, дело в том, что Google Sheets API без каких либо ограничений позволяет проходить авторизацию через сервисные аккаунты, не используя браузер. А Google Ads API, позволяет это делать, только при использовании Google Workspace. Подробнее об этом можно узнать по [ссылке](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts).

На самом деле вопрос в другом, почему у вас слетает закешированный токен? У меня он без проблем работает на протяжении уже нескольких месяцев, и ни разу не слетал.

Попробуйте разобраться, что именно ломает токен, в какой момент это происходит. На самом деле срок жизни токена всего час, далее пакет его автоматически обновляет, и так происходит через каждый час.

В процессе авторизации подробно можно разобраться изучив документацию пакета `gargle` - https://gargle.r-lib.org/